# Block users from accessing other Wordpress posts through pagination

Tags: php, wordpress

I want visitors to only see the 10 latest posts on my homepage. I've hid all pagination links, but a visitor can still type the URL manually and load the previous posts:

www.example.com/page/2

How can I disable this so a visitor can't browse my archive? It can either be a 404 or redirect to homepage. Thanks.

Comment: I think that a content_pagination filter might do the trick for you - have a look at [birgire's solution here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/208784/93169)

Comment: None of those 3 examples work, unfortunately.

Comment: Ouch. Well in that case, the only other solution I can think of is to assign a static page as your front page, and use a custom shortcode to loop through blog posts and output them on there. That way you can control what is shown, and no parameter/url bypassing can occur. The only problem with that is that people will still be able to bypass all of that by using custom search query parameter.

Comment: I blocked all searches through a plugin, all searches return No results. But even with a custom homepage, they will be able to access /page/2. I need to block that.

Comment: Did you check the "Related" column on the link Frits provided? I'm seeing this and it probably points to a solution: [Disable wordpress pagination URL rewrite for specific page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/66273/12615)... Maybe the action `template_redirect` could be of help, but am not sure...

Comment: Thanks, I'll see if I can figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect users back to the Homepage or page where you are showing your latest Posts by adding the following redirect as shown in the image below.

- Source URL: `/page/`
- Target Url: `/`

[image: Redirect To Homepage]

Comment: Hey, it worked, thanks a lot! I had to check Regex, but it works. And the plugin is this: https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/